# how could it make for the embed sent of this command to be deleted after 5s

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

how could it make for the embed sent of this command to be deleted after 5s, tried to make the message be deleted there is no error in the console, just do not delete after 5s

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const Schema = require("../../database/models/functions");

const usersMap = new Map();
const LIMIT = 5;
const TIME = 10000;
const DIFF = 3000;

module.exports = async (client) => {
    client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
        if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'DM') return;

        Schema.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
            if (data) {
                if (data.AntiSpam == true) {
                    if (usersMap.has(message.author.id)) {
                        const userData = usersMap.get(message.author.id);
                        const { lastMessage, timer } = userData;
                        const difference = message.createdTimestamp - lastMessage.createdTimestamp;
                        let msgCount = userData.msgCount;

                        if (difference > DIFF) {
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                            userData.msgCount = 1;
                            userData.lastMessage = message;
                            userData.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                                usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
                            }, TIME);
                            usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData)
                        }
                        else {
                            ++msgCount;
                            if (parseInt(msgCount) === LIMIT) {
                                message.delete();

                                client.embed({
                                    title: `${client.emotes.normal.error}・Moderator`,
                                    desc: `It is not allowed to spam in this server!`,
                                    color: client.config.colors.error,
                                    content: `${message.author}`
                                }, message.channel) 
                            } else {
                                userData.msgCount = msgCount;
                                usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        let fn = setTimeout(() => {
                            usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
                        }, TIME);
                        usersMap.set(message.author.id, {
                            msgCount: 1,
                            lastMessage: message,
                            timer: fn
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }).setMaxListeners(0);
}
```

tried to make the mention be deleted after 5s and it didn't work, wanted to know if someone who knows how to do this could be helping me put this in my bot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how your current custom embed message structure works but I'll show you how it would normally be implemented:

```js
// Construct embed
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()...;

// Send message
const message = await <TextChannel>.send({embeds: [embed]});

// Delete message after 5 seconds
setTimeout(message.delete(), 5000);
```

If you wanted to send the code for `<Client>#embed` I could potentially elaborate for a further answer.